# AspNet Core Controller GET Request using multiple variables

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to build an webapi route that will allow me to query more than 1 parameter on the objects at a time, without having to use result filtering.

Say I have a class called `AppxPackage`, and I want to search for all results that contain more than 1 parameter, in this case `WinRelease` and `WinVersion`, how do I get the results containing both?

Below is my code that I tried, it compiles, but always returns a 404 even when the results do exist.

###### AppxPackage.cs

```cs
public class AppxPackage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string[] WinRelease { get; set; }
    public string[] WinEdition { get; set; }
    public string[] WinVersion { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
[HttpGet("winversion/{winversion}/winrelease/{winrelease}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<AppxPackage>>> GetAppxPackageByWinVersion([FromRoute]string winversion, [FromRoute]string winrelease)
{
    var packages = _context.AppxPackages.Where(
                     a => a.WinVersion.Contains(winversion)
                           .WinEdition.Contains(winrelease));

    if (packages.Count() == 0)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return await packages.ToListAsync();
}
```

I have already tried a variation of the search like this too:

```cs
var packages = _context.AppxPackages.Where(a => a.WinVersion.Contains(winversion)).Where(a => a.WinEdition.Contains(winedition));
```

Both unsuccessful. Do I need to index against the returned result `packages` instead somehow?

Comment: are you sure the result exists? try print the content of  `packages`

Comment: Are  you able to debug the controller action code?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in `GetAppxPackageByWinVersion`,will it be hit?Can you share your url?

Comment: this code confuses me ```a.WinVersion.Contains(winversion)
                           .WinEdition.Contains(winrelease)```  shouldn't that be ```a.WinVersion.Contains(winversion) && a.WinEdition.Contains(winrelease)```

Comment: what is the URL you're using to test?  are you sure its actually returning 404 from your menthod and not 404 because the route isn't resolving?  Rather than 404 you should be returning 204... as in successful but NoContent();

Comment: @KeithNicholas You are right! Thank you! That sorted my issue :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for [Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10431/keith-nicholas) for his comment - I was able to amend the code and got it working:

```cs
[HttpGet("winversion/{winversion}/winrelease/{winrelease}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<AppxPackage>>> GetAppxPackageByWinVersion([FromRoute]string winversion, [FromRoute]string winrelease)
{
    var packages = _context.AppxPackages.Where(
                     a => a.WinVersion.Contains(winversion) &&
                          a.WinEdition.Contains(winrelease));

    if (packages.Count() == 0)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return await packages.ToListAsync();
}
```

I was not using the correct syntax, and now this is operating exactly how I intended it to work. Thank you for your support!